# Object doesn't support property or method 'Deferred'

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, onclientclick

I have implemented a `javascript` confirmation dialog.
The dialog will open `onClientClick` event:

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnIssuerRemove" runat="server" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" 
        CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Remove" Text="Remove" OnCommand="issuerCommand_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateBinExists()"/>
```

When button is clicked it should open a dialog with "OK" and "Cancel" butotns:

```
function ValidateBinExists() {
    if ($('#cphBody_gvBins').find("input[value='Edit']").length > 0 || $('#cphBody_gvBins').find("input[value='Update']").length > 0) {
        ShowDialog().then(function (answer) {
            console.log(answer);
            return answer;
        });

    }
}

function ShowDialog() {

    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $("#dialogBox").dialog({
       title: "System Message",
       modal: true,
       resizable: false,
       width: 250,
       buttons: {
           "Cancel": function () {
               defer.resolve(false);
               $(this).dialog('close');
           },
           "OK": function () {
               defer.resolve(true);
               $(this).dialog('close');
           }
        }
   });

    return defer.promise();
}
```

However, when clicking the button, nothing happens because I have a `javascript` error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'Deferred'

How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Deferred and promise - Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'then'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246211/jquery-deferred-and-promise-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method)

Comment: Did you include jQuery? What version is it? Can you do `console.log($)` please?